# what does "painfully obvious" mean?

Tags: phrases

According to Longman Dictionary, *painfully* means :

> 1-  very – used to emphasize a bad or harmful quality that someone or something has
>   2- needing a lot of effort

This is the text:

> "...and his college basketball days are far enough behind him that his chest muscles have turned into saggy manboobs that were **painfully obvious** through his freebie dot-com polo shirts." - *Little Brother* by Cory Doctorow

Is it "very obvious to find out" or "it needs a lot effort to find it out"?

Comment: "If a problem is painfully clear/obvious, etc, it is embarrassing because it is so clear/obvious, etc" [- Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/painfully)

Comment: It's a transferred modifier, as with a _proud_ day. The people present on the day are proud, and the observers are observing with grimaces.

Comment: @Lawrence: Please consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: It should be blindingly obvious that understanding my point here doesn't involve damaging your eyesight.

Answer (score 1):

The term *painfully* here takes on the meaning of *very* as you have it in your definition 1, except that the 'harm' is usually one of embarrassment.

> If a problem is painfully clear/obvious, etc, it is embarrassing because it is so clear/obvious, etc:
>   *It was painfully obvious that she didn't like him.*
>   [- Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/painfully)

Answer (score -1):

In that context "painfully" means the same as "painful" in "painful to see" although "obvious" implies it is difficult to avoid seeing.

Comment: I would appreciate knowing what the reason for the down-vote is.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvote was because your answer merely refers to the use of the word "painfully" in another phrase rather than actually explaining it's meaning.